Schema selection with sqlalchemy in postgres database
I am trying to create SQLalchemy ORM tables in a postgresql database. The database code looks like following:
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column


metadata = sa.MetaData(schema='simulation')


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    metadata = metadata


class DBNetwork(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'networks'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(sa.String(60))
    type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(sa.String(20))
    year: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.Integer)

I am importing this code to the main.py and running additional upload/download functions. I implemented the metadata = sa.MetaData(schema='simulation') in order to be able to change schemas. However, each time I need to change schema I need to change this database code. Is there any way I can do it inside the main.py? Like after creating the classes like DBNetwork or Base, can I change the metadata attribute of Base class?
